# How to modify default.aspx in sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I am new in the SharePoint and I am working in a project has two English and French websites.
I have a subside in both English and French websites are using a calendar web part.

But, as the theme used in the English site is different to the French one, the Calendars colors are different.

I got the default.aspx pages are using different style sheet files in the header so my assumption is that I can change the link of style sheets in the default.aspx French site to be the same as English one and then the calendar's color would be the same too. (It should be mentioned I compared both of calendar.css files are the same but core.css files are different)

However, I don't know how can I get the default.aspx page to edit or which permission do I need to have or SharePoint designer must be installed in my machine or any extensions in the web server?

Also, I tried to edit the masterpage in the sharepoint designer but it gives me below error:

This type of page is not served.
Server Error in '/' Application.  This type of page is not served.    Description: The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.master' may be incorrect.   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly.   Requested URL: /_catalogs/masterpage/default.master  Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3649; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3648

Please help me to solve my problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like someone have turned of SharePoint Designer access on the server side. The error message says that you are forbidden.
In general you need to have the "Design" permission to edit those files.

If SharePoint Designer is forbidden, then your only chance is to download the files that needs to be modified.. This can be accomplished if you go to the list view and select 
"Send to" -> "Download a copy".

Then you can try to make the changes offline and re-upload the changes.
For the master page you also need to do the following:

- check out master page file
- upload the changed file
- check in the new
  master page as major version
- approve the master page